# JavaScript use hundreds of closure or one function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a data web page with possibly few thousands TDs in it.  Some of the TD's will need a bound onclick event that uses the contents, or part of the contents of the TD.

I'm using jQuery to add the onclick closure like this:

```
$(".date").click(function() {
    var d = this.html();
    doSomething(this, d, otherparams);
}
```

Is this efficient?  It seems that my page would contain few hundreds, or thousands of almost identical closures.  Would it be better to put this `doSomething` call somewhere else.

Comment: `$(".date")` is a selector. and so you don't have "few hundreds, or thousands of almost identical closures."

Comment: FWIW, you are not creating *few hundreds, or thousands of almost identical closures*. You are creating only **one** event handler which is assigned to a lot of elements (see, it is the same: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/dduqL/). Event delegation is still better though because you don't have to find all the `.date` elements in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Infact, this is **very** inefficient. Even more because you can so easily workaround it using **event delegation**. Doing that, will use only **one** event handler method instead of "thousands".

```
$('table').delegate('td.date', 'click', function( event ) {
    var d = $(this).html();
    doSomething(this, d, otherparams);
});
```

You need to call this construct only once (outside of any loop). It'll bind an click event handler to all tables in the above example (you should be more precise using an id for instance). Since most browser events do "bubble" up the DOM tree, any click which happens in a `<td>` element will finally reach the `<table>` and is processed there.

Ref.: [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: wow, I didn't know about it - nice :) btw: there is a syntax error: `var d = $(this).html():` - the line should end with `;` :)

Comment: Now that makes much more sense.  I had a feeling i was not the right thing.  :-)

Comment: Should probably be `td.date`.

Comment: @Felix: yay. I just wasn't sure what to use there. Should also not be "table", but I mentioned that.

Comment: @jAndy: True, I missed the part *or part of the contents of the TD* so it could also be something else... nvm! :)